# How to separate date and time from timestamp and store it in another table in hive

Tags: date, hadoop, time, hive, timestamp

I have installed hive 2.1.1 on hadoop where I have created table with name data with columns (dis string,dt timestamp). I wanted to store date and time in separate columns so i created another table with name data1 and columns (dis string, dat date,time string). How can i copy data from table data to data1.
I have tried to it by doing "insert into table data1 select dis,convert(date,dt),convert(time,dt) from data;".

Answer (score 0):

use below query

```
insert into table data1 select dis,TO_DATE(dt),concat(HOUR(DT),':',MINUTE(dt)) from data;
```

Comment: (1) what with the seconds? (2) why using `concat` and not `concat_ws`?

Comment: i have just provided sample to include time there , we can use according to our requirement. yes we can also use concat_ws also .. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
select dis,to_date(dt),split(dt,' ')[1]
```

or

```
select dis,to_date(dt),substr(dt,12,8)
```

**Demo**

```
with t as (select timestamp '2017-04-06 04:20:33' as dt) 
select to_date(dt),split(dt,' ')[1] from t;
OK
_c0 _c1
2017-04-06  04:20:33
```

---

```
with t as (select timestamp '2017-04-06 04:20:33' as dt) 
select to_date(dt),substr(dt,12,8) from t;
OK
_c0 _c1
2017-04-06  04:20:33
```